# Maintaining scroll position within page after CSS event without JS?

Tags: html, css

I have a single large page with a series of "slides" and a menu to select which one you would like to view. The links in the menu take you to the appropriate slide but opening or closing the menu returns you to the top of the page, completely defeating the purpose.

I am using CSS to push the menu into view when the menu button is clicked; how can I prevent the page from changing scroll position after opening/closing the menu? I would like to avoid using JS if possible but can if necessary.

Menu opening CSS:

```
.nav-trigger:checked + label{
    left: 200px;
}

.nav-trigger:checked ~ main{
    left: 200px;
}
```

CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Rappqg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the click will make the page scroll to where the checkbox is in the visible window frame. A solution is quite straightforward: set `.nav-trigger` to `position: fixed;`.

[Updated CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/reymEm).

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

Could be wrong, but I think it's not possible with css only. The onliest way to prevent the default action in css is to use `pointer-events: none`, but this would not affect the scroll behaviour of your page.

With javascript you could either use `event.preventDefault()` or just `return false` in your event handler.

However, this would not work with checkboxes, as they trigger just before the checkbox changes. So, to make it work you could do something like this:

```
var scrollX, scrollY

// Listen to click-event and get the current scroll offset
document.querySelector('label[for="nav-trigger"]').addEventListener('click', function () {
  scrollX = window.pageXOffset
  scrollY = window.pageYOffset
})

// Apply the cached scroll offset when the checkbox changes
document.querySelector('.nav-trigger').addEventListener('change', function () {
  window.scrollTo(scrollX, scrollY)
})
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wGJdOV